# Console.Writeline is only writing to the console some of the times when using async await

Tags: c#, async-await

So, I have a super simple application, but as I am testing this out it is only writing to the console from the method DoWork().  I am unsure why that is, but I am fairly sure it has to do with the fact that it is async code.  Any ideas, why it only writes from method DoWork()?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync().Wait();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            List<Task> myWork = new List<Task>();
            myWork.Add(DoWork(i));
            if (myWork.Count == 50)
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(myWork);
                Console.WriteLine("before delay");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("after delay");
                myWork.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("List cleared.");
            }
        }


    }

    public static async Task DoWork(int i)
    {
        await Task.Delay(0);
        Console.WriteLine("Run: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the application ever exit?

Comment: Tip: If you are using C# 7.0 or newer, you don't need the non-async version of your `main` method.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Why wouldn't it exit? The only completely, utterly wrong I can see is that `Thread.Sleep(50000);`

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and include the current output and the expected one? The answer by @Idle_Mind does not seem to be what you are asking about, at least to me

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto because I've seen it millions (exaggerated) of times when someone posts code that doesn't match what they are *actually doing*, and what they are actually doing is causing an async/await deadlock.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm sure you exaggerated and only saw it some 900.000's times :)

Comment: No Idle_Mind is correct. The `Console.WriteLine()`s in the MainAsync method never get executed because the `myWork` list never reaches a count of 50 because it gets created anew every time through the loop. If you move it outside of the loop then the delay and console writelines work as expected.

Comment: The given answer correctly points out that you are creating 300 lists, not one list, and putting one item in each. However, **you are required to ensure that the list is only accessed from one thread**, or that the type given is threadsafe.  Do not be misled by plausible but unsafe code; make sure you understand thoroughly what you're doing when you write a console app that uses asynchrony. The threading context does not use the same rules as a winforms app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new List for each iteration of the loop...it will only ever have one thing in it.

Declare the List **outside** of the loop.

Change:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        List<Task> myWork = new List<Task>();
```

To:

```
    List<Task> myWork = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
```

Comment: Suppose you do this; what guarantees that the list will only be accessed on one thread?

Comment: My answer doesn't deal with the thread safety issue at all.  Need to start with a fix somewhere without writing an entire book.   =)   Feel free to address this topic in your answers...

Comment: Writing a dangerously wrong answer, not calling that out, and hoping an expert steps in to fix it is not a great practice for this site.

Comment: Some light reading for you: [Thread-Safe Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/)

Comment: @EricLippert But the list *is* accessed on only one thread simultanesoulsy? The `await` may make it hop between threads, but I believe `await` introduces a point of synchronization, so after `await`ing the method will see the writes it did before `await`ing.

Comment: @Joker_vD: The model you're describing, where an object can be accessed on multiple threads but only one "at a time" is called "rental threading". Is the `List<T>` class documented as being safe for rental threading? The C# specification documents that certain events, like starting a thread or throwing an exception, have special behavior with regard to ordering multithreaded effects; does it describe `await` as one of those events?  If the answer to either question is no, then a program might work *by accident*, but it is not *known* to be correct.

Comment: @EricLippert Sadly, much of this isn't documented. For example, `Interlocked.Increment`  does introduce a sync point, but it's not documented anywhere. It's really sad, because `async`/`await` syntax strongly implies that "rental model" is the way to go (e.g., `await`ing inside a `lock` is prohibited).

Comment: Thanks, looks like I needed another set of eyes.